# NetLogo: storing variables in list and iterating through them

Tags: list, iteration, netlogo

I want to loop through a range of variables in NetLogo. Idea is that those values are inserted as variables in UI and those values are iterated through in `while` or `foreach` loop. Also how to get to each value - in Python it is easy as you iterate through them but if I use NetLogo then I have to take "item x in list", can I access variables in list same way? In Python it is like below:

```
variables = [x0, x1, x2, x3, x4]
for x in variables:
    print (x)
```

Output is x0 to x4 as variables to use in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to put variables from the UI into a list, you can use the `list` primitive to build a list of variables that the user input, for example using an "Input" in the UI. Then, you can use `foreach` to iterate through the items in that list.

```
  let x_list (list x0 x1 x2 x3 x4 )

  foreach x_list [ 
    [x] ->
    print(x)
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Luck's answer is correct. But if you have a ton of similarly named variables, be aware that you can also do something like:

```
let xs map [ [n] -> runresult word "x" n ] range 5
foreach xs [ [x] ->
  print x
]
```